# /etc/timezone does not exist on anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre docker image

Tags: java, docker, java-8, docker-compose

I want to know, what time zone on my docker container that runs on anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre image. But I cant find /etc/timezone - it doesnt exist. If I open ect/localtime it shows me:

> TZif2UTCTZif2�UTC UTC0

Does it mean my docker default timezone is UTC?

I start container with docker-compose. I dont modify anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to install `tzdata` first on the image since it does not there:

```
apk add --no-cache tzdata
```

to check the timezone:

```
cat /etc/localtime
```

Copy the zone to localtime:

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime
```

set your new timezone:

```
echo "Europe/Berlin" >  /etc/timezone
```

and yes your timetone is UTC in the current image

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by LinPy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103173/642706) is presumably correct for the Linux part of your Question. But you also tagged your question for Java.

## Java has *tzdata*

Java has its own copy of the time zone database, [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Any time zone database in your host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is irrelevant within the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

If rules are changing for a time zone in which you are interested, be sure to update the *tzdata* in at least three places:

- Operating system (Linux, BSD, macOS, and such)
- Java platform
- Database system ([Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), and such)

Frequent updates to Java will include a recent *tzdata*. Unfortunately, politicians have been getting reckless with changing the time zone(s) of their jurisdiction with [little](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/turkey-scraps-dst-2016.html) or [no](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-44010705) forewarning. In such a case, you may need to [manually install](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20tzdata%20update&t=osx&ia=web) a fresh *tzdata*.

To capture the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), call [`Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
```

Adjust into a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z  ;
```

Comment: While Java has it's own tzdata, openjdk still parses `/etc/timezone` to determine the default timezone and defaults to GTM (rather then UTC) if absent.